# Angular 2 ngModel not updated after restful call

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I have a simple user component that retrieve user's firstname and lastname. When user click on the submit button, it will make a restful call and retrieve the details and pass back to my user object. However, this is not happening at the moment and I'm not sure what went wrong.

When I initiate the model during init manually, the form will display the user's data correctly. If I retrieve and assign the values back to the form from the Rest API call, the form is not being updated.

I've verified the data is being retrieved correctly, my diagnostic method also shows the model has the response data mapped correctly. I've tried the zone.run but the form is not updated too.

***UPDATE***
I found out the reason is because the response is an array of objects. Changing the following has resolved the issue.

```
this.model = new User().fromJSON(user)[0];
```

I'm not sure whether there is any way to ensure my service always return an JSON object instead of an array of objects?

**userservice.ts**

```
 return this.http.post('http://ng2nodejs.azurewebsites.net/api/user', data , {
            headers: authHeader
        })
        .map((response: Response) => { return response.json()});
```

**My user component** - The diagnostic is displaying the data correctly though

```
{{diagnostic}}

<h1>User Form</h1>
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && getUser()" #f="ngForm" >                        
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
       <input type="text" id="firstname" [(ngModel)]="model.firstname" name="firstname" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
       <input type="text" id="lastname" [(ngModel)]="model.lastname" name="lastname" >
    </div>  

    <button>Submit</button>                
</form>
```

**The user model**, the fromJSON method is to convert the response to my user model.

```
export class User {
  username: string;      
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string; 

  fromJSON(json) {
        for (var propName in json)
            this[propName] = json[propName];
        return this;
    }
}
```

**My component**

```
 import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
 import { User } from '../auth/user';
 import { UserService } from '../auth/user.service';

 @Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'app-first',
   templateUrl: './first.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./first.component.css'],

 })
 export class FirstComponent {
     constructor(private userService: UserService, private zone:NgZone) { }  
     model =  new User();    
     getUser() {             
          this.userService
             .getUser('User123')
             .subscribe((user: Object) => {
                  this.zone.run(() => { 
                     this.model = new User().fromJSON(user);     
                  });  
             });
     }

     get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.model); }
 }
```

Comment: when do you call your method `getUser()` ? You should call it onInit or in the constructor.

Comment: what does ` this.model = new User().fromJSON(user); ` returns in console. try logging 'this.model'.

Comment: try `this.model = this.model.fromJSON(user);` inside `getUser` method

Comment: @mickdev getUser is called by the form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && getUser()"

Comment: @candidJ console.log is showing the retrieved user object, replacing new User with this.model did not work.

Comment: That's a little weird to me. Did you try to call it in constructor so it'll set the value of model at component construction?

Comment: @mickdev Yes. I tried that as well when the form is initiated. Seems like the ngForm model and the component model is detached.

Comment: I don't know that any of these minor oversights is causing your problem but it can't hurt to fix them: 1) button should be `<button type="submit">`; 2) user instantiation would be cleaner as `new User(jsonData)` and then let the constructor deal with jsonData; 3) I don't think you need zone.run(). SIDE NOTE: so you have a form in which the user enters values and when they submit you override the form values with the result of an http call? it might not be optimal in terms of user-friendliness.

Comment: You are right. Regarding the sitenote, this is more like a POC to test the binding, when user click on the Submit it will retrieve the user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your issue, but I would give some pointers here.

If you really don't have a reason to use Classes, I would suggest you'd move to interfaces:

```
export interface User {
  username: string;      
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string; 
}
```

and NgZone shouldn't be needed here.

```
export class FirstComponent {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }  
  model: User = {};   

  getUser() {             
    this.userService
      .getUser('User123')
      .subscribe((user: Object) => {
         this.model = user;
      });
  }
}
```

And if you have control of your API, why not return the newly created user when you actually create the new User, so that you do not need to make a separate http call to get the user.

With the above at least **[this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/th6iJEudjzxNN1NzbXYO?p=preview)** seems to be working well. The properties are a bit different, since I use mockbackend here.

Comment: If this does not work, you could try and recreate the issue in a plunker?

Comment: Thanks. I did a quick test using your codes and I'm getting an error Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'User'. Property 'firstname' is missing in type '{}' for the model: User = {}; The plunker seems to be working fine though.

Comment: Yaah, the error is when you are instantiating the User Object? Try this: `model = <User>{};`

Comment: Not really. The main reason is the response returned is an array, the solution is  this.model = new User().fromJSON(user)[0]; which I updated in my question.